# Have all previous commits be repushed as one commit in git on master branch

Tags: git, github, git-fork, squash

I have a forked repo that I have been committing changes to on master of this forked repo. I have another patch I wanted to push to my forked master repo, but I wanted to figure out how to do it so that it would still only show as one commit in my commit history so it's more organized when I do a pull request on the actual repo with my fork.

Comment: If you develop on a feature branch in your forked repo, you can open the PR back to the 'masterr repo' and squash merge. Your master branch would only be used to sync from the upstream master.

Comment: @osowskit The problem is that I have already opened the PR and received peer review so I am trying to figure out how to do it to the fork so it is reflected in the pull request too and doesn't show anything more than a single commit.

Comment: Concise PR comments against code is better than clean/linear branch history. Squash merge into the upstream repo if it is a requirement for that project.